# how could I create link in tableau from a row to another dashboards

Tags: hyperlink, tableau-api, dashboard

I used `Tableau Software 10.5`
I have couple of dashboards and I want create `hyperlink` on each of rows.
precisly when users click on each row of data in grid or chart .... then they go to another dashboards with that filter on pervious dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple

Go to the Dashboard in the top menu bar and select action(ctrl+shift+D)
then click add action and select type as the "filter".

now choose source sheet and target sheet, select target filters and select "Select" in run action on
you are done.

Comment: thank you pal. my problem fixed. Please score to my question if is useful